# How to change orientation but keep auto rotage screen

Tags: android, orientation

when you click fullscreen icon in youtube app, it will change to landscape and fullscreen , devece still auto rotage mode, how to do that?

if set lanscape mode : `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` (**device always landscape**)

1. **click fullscreen**

[image: Click fullscreen]

2. **lanscape**

[image: Lanscape]

3. **portrait**

[image: portrain]

**I SOLVED MY PROBLEM** using sensor to detect landscape or portrait

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    videoview.pause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mRotationSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mRotationSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor == mRotationSensor) {
        if (event.values.length > 4) {
            float[] truncatedRotationVector = new float[4];
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, truncatedRotationVector, 0, 4);
            update(truncatedRotationVector);
        } else {
             update(event.values);
        }
    }

}

private void update(float[] vectors) {
    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, vectors);
    int worldAxisX = SensorManager.AXIS_X;
    int worldAxisZ = SensorManager.AXIS_Z;
    float[] adjustedRotationMatrix = new float[9];
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, worldAxisX, worldAxisZ, adjustedRotationMatrix);
    float[] orientation = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getOrientation(adjustedRotationMatrix, orientation);
    // float pitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]);
    float roll = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[2]);

    boolean curentOrient = isPortrait;
    if(roll >= -75 && roll <= 75){
        isPortrait = true;
        System.out.println("Portrait");
    }else{
        isPortrait = false;
        System.out.println("Landscape");
    }
    if(curentOrient != isPortrait){
        videoview.toggleFullScreen(isPortrait); // this is my videoview.
    }
}
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}
```

and let **implements SensorEventListener**

Answer (score 1):

Use `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_SENSOR`.

Comment: ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_SENSOR, i tried but it only allow landscape, not portrait. thank you sir

Comment: So, you just want full screen but sensor orientation? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you click fullscreen button you can open new activity with only landscape orientation. Just play video there.

Comment: thank you man, but when change activity video have to reload to play

Answer (score 0):

In case when you will use only youtube video youtube API can help you.
As i know YoutubeActivity can save progress when you rotate device. Here link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/?hl=ru